# $inc modifier increments by 2 instead of 1 - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, activerecord, yii2

I am using Yii2 framework and running the following query on my database. After running the query, score value increments by 2 instead of 1. Is there any problem you see with my code!?

```
$model = new UserTags;
$model->find()
      ->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id, 'tag' => 'something'])
      ->modify(['$inc' => ['score' => 1]], ['upsert' => true]);
```

Comment: what does your data look like? What was the older value of the score, was it 0? Are you sure that the code wasn't executed twice?

Comment: When I put the code in my controller it increase the value 2 times but when I copy it into "afterSave" method in my model it works fine!!!!